# How do I connect menus together and navigate between them in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, menu

i'm relatively new to python.

bellow is part of the code I have been working on
The main issue that is occurring for me at the moment is that i cannot navigate between the main menu and the other menus I have created. When I attempt to it just proceeds to the next menu until it finishes the program.

```
def main():
    menuSelect = ""
    print("\tPersonal Date, Gadget Inventory, Exit")

#main menu
print ("\n\t\tWelcome Admin!")
print("\n\t\tMain Menu")
print("\t1. Personal Data")
print("\t2. Gadget Inventory")
print("\t3. Quit")

menuSelect = int(input("\nPlease select one of the Three options "))

while menuSelect < 1 or menuSelect > 3:
    print("The selection provided is invalid.")
    menuSelect = int(input("\nPlease select one of the three options "))

    if menuSelect == 1:
        personalData()
    elif menuSelect == 2:
        gadgetInventory()
    elif menuSelect == 3:
        quit()


#personal data Menu
def personalData():
    menuSelect == ""
    print("\tCreate New, Current Users, Salary Calculator, Main Menu")
    
#personal data menu
print ("\n\t\tHello Admin!")
print("\n\t\tPersonal Data")
print("\t1. Create New")
print("\t2. Current Users")
print("\t3. Salary Calculator")
print("\t4. Main Menu")
menuSelect = int(input("\nPlease select one of the four options "))

while menuSelect < 1 or menuSelect > 4:
    print("The selection provided is invalid.")
    menuSelect = int(input("\nPlease select one of the four options "))

    if menuSelect == 1:
        createNew()
    elif menuSelect == 2:
        currentUsers()
    elif menuSelect == 3:
        salaryCalculator()
    elif menuSelect == 4:
        main()

#quit menu
def quit():
    again = ""

    if again=="yes" or again=="y":
        input('Press ENTER to exit')    
    else:
        main()
    
    
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick look at your code, you are going along the right lines but I think the structure is out of sync eg selecting 3 at the first opportunity does not quit the program.
Have you tried stepping through the program in an IDE like Thonny, it will show you how your program is branching.
I have not attempted to solve your problem for you because you can do it, you just need to do some pseudo-code to determine how you want the program to flow through its operations.

Comment: I ended up re-writing my code and making it less complex after several videos and tutorials as well as adding the break function. thank you susan

Comment: cool! It a great step when we have our own ah-ha moments.